# RethinkDB - JavaScript Join multiple items

Tags: javascript, nosql, rethinkdb

I have the following data structure:

```
  persons
[
    {
        id:1,
        firstname:'My name',
        talks[
            {
                talk_id:1,
                since:2018-01-01
            },
            {
                talk_id:2,
                since:2018-01-01
            },
            {
                talk_id:3,
                since:2018-01-01
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id:2,
        firstname:'Other name',
        talks[
            {
                talk_id:1,
                since:2018-01-01
            }           
        ]
    }
]


talks
[
    {
        id:1
        name:'Talk about something'
    },
    {
        id:2
        name:'Talk about something else'
    },
    {
        id:3
        name:'Talk about nothing'
    }
]
```

I want a merged object of persons with all the talks inside that are assigned to this person. 
I've tried to solve it by myself with the examples given in the documentation, but I cannot figure out how to archive this.

Maybe my datastructure is not in the right noSQL way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way of doing this would be:

```
r.db('tedtalks').table('persons')
.getAll(/* select people here I suppose */)
.merge({
  talks: r.row('talks').map(function (talk) {
    return talk.merge({
      talk: r.db('tedtalks').table('talks').get(talk('talk_id'))
    });
  })
});
```

Your result would look like:

```
[
    {
        id:1,
        firstname:'My name',
        talks[
            {
                talk_id:1,
                since:2018-01-01,
                talk: {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Talk about something'
                }
            },
            {
                talk_id:2,
                since:2018-01-01,
                talk: {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Talk about something else'
                }
            },
            {
                talk_id:3,
                since:2018-01-01,
                talk: {
                    id: 3,
                    name: 'Talk about nothing'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id:2,
        firstname:'Other name',
        talks[
            {
                talk_id:1,
                since:2018-01-01,
                talk: {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Talk about something'
                }
            }           
        ]
    }
]
```

In the `.map` call, you may want to return an object directly, to get rid of `talk_id`:

```
    return {
      talk: r.db('tedtalks').table('talks').get(talk('talk_id')),
      since: talk('since')
    };
```

Or even everything at the same level (as long as keys don't overlap):

```
    return r.db('tedtalks').table('talks').get(talk('talk_id')).merge({
      since: talk('since')
    });
```

Well, you got the idea.